# Socket.io emit not working (by visiting URL)

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, websocket, socket.io

I am developing an app that gets a signal from external hardware equipment. I catch this signal by redirecting it to a certain URL in my app: '/impulse/:id'.

I am able to catch the signal, but the emit function inside the app.get('/impulse/:id') is not triggering. The console logs are...

How can I make the emit function work?

Below is my server.js script, where I catch all the socket signals and prevent the external call from being redirected to the index page.

```
...
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
const socket = require('socket.io');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
app.use('/api', appRoutes); 


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://HERE IS MY DB INFO...', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Not connected to the database: ' + err); // Log to console if unable to connect to database
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB'); // Log to console if able to connect to database
    }
});

var server = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Running the server on port ' + port); // Listen on configured port
});

var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('join', function(data){
        var gameroom = data.gameid;   
        console.log("joined: " + gameroom)     
        socket.join(gameroom);
    })

   //FUNCTION I WANT TO TRIGGER
    socket.on('impulse', function(data){
        console.log('IMPULSE')
        io.emit('impulseReceived', {

        })
    })

})

//PLACE WHERE I EMIT
app.get('/impulse/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log('Impulse Received')
    var time = req.query.TIME;
    var gameroom = req.params.id; 

    io.on('connect', function (socket) {
       socket.emit('impulse', {
       })
    })

    res.json({ success: true, message: 'received the time!'})
})

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html')); // Set index.html as layout
});
```

Comment: Did you get this figured out?  @RutgerBms

Answer (score 0):

Replace this whole

```
io.on('connect', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('impulse', {
    })
}
```

with this

```
io.emit('impulse', {})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I changed the code like you said (see the main thread code part for my changes) but it is still not sending. Only console output I get is: 'Impulse Received'. Should be seeing 'IMPULSE'....